# What java API can I use to extract the names from a PyTorch model file?

Tags: java, pytorch

I have been given a pytorch model file, and some object detection results.  The object detection results give number to identify what kind of object it detected, but I want the names from the model file.

Some python code I found looks like this

```
model = DetectMultiBackend(weights, device=device, dnn=dnn, data=data, fp16=half)
stride, names, pt = model.stride, model.names, model.pt
```

I am pretty sure I need to get the `names` array, but I'm working in java, not python.  I looked into the `ai.djl.pytorch.engine.PtModel`, but could not spot anything that looks like a mapping from numbers to names.

It even looks like DeepJavaLibrary can't support loading a plain `.pt` file:

```
String fname = "/tmp/yolov5s.pt"; 
{
    PtEngine engine = (PtEngine) Engine.getEngine("PyTorch");
    Model model = engine.newModel("bacon", null);
    model.load(new File(fname).toPath());
    Block block = model.getBlock();
    System.out.println(block);
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" ai.djl.engine.EngineException: PytorchStreamReader failed locating file constants.pkl: file not found
    at ai.djl.pytorch.jni.PyTorchLibrary.moduleLoad(Native Method)
    at ai.djl.pytorch.jni.JniUtils.loadModule(JniUtils.java:1550)
    at ai.djl.pytorch.engine.PtModel.load(PtModel.java:90)
    at ai.djl.Model.load(Model.java:110)
    at project.pictureServer.PyTorchFile.main(PyTorchFile.java:37)
```

What is the proper way to map from object/class numbers to names using Java and a PyTorch model file?

Comment: AFAIK, pyTorch saves model files in [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) format.  This might be a good option to read pickle files: https://formats.kaitai.io/python_pickle/java.html

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is the proper way to map from a pyTorch model file to Java objects?

A: I believe a pyTorch model file is just a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) serialization of Python objects.  One alternative might be [PythonPickle](https://formats.kaitai.io/python_pickle/java.html).

---

Your challenge is to read a PyTorch (.pt?) model file in Java.

- One alternative is to "reverse engineer" those parts of the format you're interested in, and write your own ".pt decoder".

  It sounds like you've already started down this path, and had some success.  If this works for you - great!
- Since a ".pt" file is just  "pickled Python", I suggested trying PythonPickle.  It's very "lightweight", and it looked like it might do everything you're looking for - and more.
- Yet another alternative might be [DeepJavaLibrary](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary), a set of Java-language bindings for pyTorch.
- Who knows - you might even want to write a little Python script to a) read a .pt file, b) write it to JSON.

Anyway - please let us know what you decide.

Comment: That web page includes java source for PythonPickle.java.  Does that java exist in a maven artifact, or is the dev expected to copy & paste that source code into their project?

Comment: Using the PythonPickle.java as suggested in the example, the ops() method returns a long stream of code like 
BINUNICODE external.PythonPickle$Unicodestring4@78d23d6a
LONG_BINPUT 7162
NONE external.PythonPickle$NoArg@626e0c86
BINUNICODE external.PythonPickle$Unicodestring4@28ee0a3c
which is not very informative.

Comment: Please see my updates above.  Please let us know what you decide.